# Why have to use value.length?

Tags: java

guys.....Please help!!!

[This is the picture of a textbook page that I'm reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFaRN.png)

So I'm reading this textbook which is totally horrible, they just give codes out without any explanation.....And this is my first class in Java, I've never coded in any language before......So like a textbook without explanation just totally....you know....give me a super hard time....

Back to topic, in the picture, there are 2 sets of codes, A and B.....I understand B......But I do not get why in A, it used `value.length` instead of `inputs.length`? Isn't the array name in this code is `inputs`??? Is there any specific reason has to use `value.length` instead of `array name.length`???

Comment: *This is the picture of the textbook page that I'm reading*. A new low in homework questions?

Comment: looks like an editing mistake in your textbook unless there is context not included in your screenshot. `.length` is a property of an array in java, and it's called on whatever reference you want to know the length of (in this case it would be your inputs array) All I can really recommend is finding a better textbook or some beginner's Java videos on youtube. If the text isn't explaining itself... it's clearly not a very useful text.

Comment: But the real question is why read a terrible textbook when there are plenty of good resources available

Comment: @ScaryWombat from the looks of what he's reading... this person is clearly on the _very_ beginner end of the spectrum. It can be a lot harder for a beginner to tell if the resource they are learning from is actually viable or not.

Comment: @AnthonyAudette A very good point

Comment: Did you pay *money* for this book? Did you check for an *errata* page?

Comment: @AnthonyAudette  It's a required textbook for my first java class in school this semester, I minor in computer science ..........>.<

Comment: Then your education institution has forced you to waste your money and that can not be helped. You should still get your information from better sources than a faulty textbook. The only _neccessary_ function of required textbooks for courses is the homework questions. The actual information you need to learn is widely available. Lynda.com has a lot of good beginner Java material, theNewBoston on youtube is also a very good source. As for text information, i recommend online research for specific subjects, i.e. Arrays in this case. For Java, Oracle's own javadocs and tutorials are amazing too.

Comment: @AnthonyAudette Thank you for your help! I'll check out the resources you recommended!......xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the book clearly has an error, don't worry, should be inputs instead values, I say it with confidence because no variable values was ever initiated